# How Can My Win32 App Steal Focus From My UWP App?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10

I've tried the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hwnd);

void TakeFocus()
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("myProcess").FirstOrDefault();
    if (process != null)
    {
        // Tried each of the following:
        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1);
        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 3);
        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 9);
        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 5);
        SetFocus(process.MainWindowHandle);
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    }
}
```

I have a WPF companion app which runs in the background while a UWP app is running in the foreground.  They communicate via WebSocket.  I'm trying to create a method in the WPF app so it (or any other window) can steal focus from an activated UWP app, sending it into suspended state.  Nothing I try seems to work, and there's no way to programatically make a UWP app suspend itself AFAIK without using the Launcher class (not an option for me, unless there's a way to call it without actually launching something-I haven't been able to do this). Normally I would assume it can't be done but I've seen programs that do it.  Steam Big Picture Mode, for example, will steal focus from a UWP app when it is launched from a background process.

Comment: Did you try setting keyboard focus? It seems a bit obvious, but...

Comment: Thanks I hadn't tried that.  Unfortunately no it didn't work.  I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported way of suspending a UWP programmatically is available in the Spring 2018 update for Windows 10. It's already available in Insider builds/SDKs. This is the API to call:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startsuspendasync#Windows_System_AppResourceGroupInfo_StartSuspendAsync

```
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
```

Here is a trivial sample app:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNoYQ3PrmBfZIGXmbULA

Comment: Nice!  I read about the new restart app feature but must have missed this.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation on how to implement AppResourceGroupInfo in the manifest?

Comment: I have added a code snippet to the answer. Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: The first line throws 'Element not found' Exception.

Comment: Are you calling this from your UWP or WPF app? The snippet I put in the answer assumes it's being called from the UWP, i.e. the app that is supposed to get suspended.

Comment: Yes of course UWP.  I'm pretty sure it wouldn't even build in WPF.  Targeting 1803. 'await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync()' throws 'Element not found' when it's called at runtime.

Comment: I tried the overload, same error: AppDiagnosticInfo appInfo = (await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync()).First();
            IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync(appInfo.AppInfo.AppUserModelId);

Comment: I also tried targeting Fall Creators and commented out StartSuspendAsync.  Still got the same error with RequestInfoForAppAsync().

Comment: I just tried it on a completely new UWP project and solution, targeting Spring Creators.  Added a button to MainPage.xaml and put your snippet in a tapped event handler.  Same error.

Comment: Running VS2017 15.6.4.  Running 64-bit Win10.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to a complete sample app. Yes, you need the capability on current build. You shouldn't actually require it when calling this for your own app, so we are looking at this as a bug. Also note that you can call this from WPF app as well. It will compile fine as long as you reference the correct Windows.winmd file. Also you will then need to call the overload with the appid, to specify which app you want to suspend.

Comment: Thank your for taking time into this.  The error is gone when adding restricted capability appDiagnostics (I had added the wrong rescap before).  FYI the new method works, but not if the app is in full screen mode.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Looking into the fullscreen mode behavior.