# c# Launching application programmatically (Process.Start) on top in tablet mode on startup

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, tablet

When application is launched it goes background. 
How could we hide Windows 10 tablet mode start screen (app tile menu) and show launched application on top ?

Comment: This article might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt784669.aspx

Comment: Can you provide more details: what type of process is doing the launch, and what kind of app are you launching?

Comment: One thing to clarify is if you use a Launcher like in Joe's link then you won't have the problem you're having.  The first app will deactivate and hide itself. Also look up FullTrustProcessLauncher which is newer than that article.  And finally if you must use Process.Start you can hide the UWP app programatically, [Stefan Wick taught me how just last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541592/how-can-my-win32-app-steal-focus-from-my-uwp-app).

Comment: I am running a background process on system boot and it listen for some key press event, on key press event, I am launching a WPF App, but it doesn't appear on top of Windows 10 tablet mode start menu, it run behind start menu screen.